# keep aspect ratio of .ui-dialog-content when resizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, aspect-ratio, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an image within the dialog. when I resize the dialog, the aspectRation is working on the complete dialog, not only on the image, when I resize it.

```
$("#videoDialog").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 300
        }).parent().resizable({
            aspectRatio: true,
            minWidth: 300
        });
```

The more I resize the dialog, the more space I get between the bottom of the image and the bottom of the dialog.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0fnbnw4L/1/

Any ideas how to fix that?

thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are resizing (and keeping the aspect ratio of) the entire dialog.

If you remove that `.parent()` call, you resize only the contents of the dialog window. But then, the dialog window don't resize with the contents, right? So you have to reset its size everytime you resize the contents.

Here is the final code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#slideDialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 100
    }).resizable({
        aspectRatio: true,
        minWidth: 100,
        resize: function (evt, ui) {
            ui.element.parent().css({width:'',height:''});
        }
    });
});
```

And the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0fnbnw4L/4/

Comment: thanks. this mostly solved my problem. I added more handles to the resizable. Now if I resize to left, the box gets broken. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0fnbnw4L/5/

Comment: it seems no one can help on my other topic regarding qjeury-ui dialog, and t seems you are pretty strong with this stufff. Do you think you could have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652209/re-position-jquery-ui-dialog-on-windows-resize? :-)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to images and sizing - you have to make some choices.

Typically you either maintain aspectRatio & clip (cut off overflow) OR adjust aspectRatio (change dimensions squishing the image) and make sure you show the entire image without clipping.

There are pros & cons to each depending on your specific application, here - the outer dialog window wasn't able to be 'resized' but you were maintaining aspectRatio on the parent, this means that it will scale the window with the image....it's not really adding more space or scaling space below your image - it's scaling the window to fit the image's width above all else, which causes additional negative space below the image.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fnbnw4L/2/

```
 $("#slideDialog").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 100
        }).parent().resizable({
            aspectRatio: true,
            minWidth: 100
     });
```

Here, I've err'ed on making sure the image fills the window as best it can using 100% of the window's width and as much (while maintaining A.R.) as it can of height.  If height is less than what the aspectRatio allows to still utilize full width, I'm clipping.

Answer (score 0):

$('#dj-manipulator').resizable({ 
    containment: 'parent',
    aspectRatio: true ,
    maxWidth: 96,
    maxHeight: 72,
    resize: function (evt, ui) {
        ui.element.parent().css({width:'',height:''});
    }
});

This solves my problem :)